# SQL - Join within the same table for matching fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table that contains 6 fields `(JobGUID, FunctionName,InFileName,InFileSize,OutFileName,OutFileSize)`

One FunctionName is *`CheckFile`*, and the other is *`UnZipFile`*. The `CheckFile`. `InFileName` and `InFileSize` should be equal to the `UnZipFile`. `OutFileName` and `OutFileSize`. I want to do a JOIN that allows me to see each side-by-side so I can compare that file sizes match.

Here is what I have so far. It seems to work, but duplicates each filename and filesize. There are 22 corresponding rows for CheckFile, and 22 rows for UnZipFile. I want it to output only 22 rows, but it outputs 44.

```
SELECT CheckFile.InFileName, CheckFile.InFileSize, 
       UnZipFile.OutFileName, UnZipFile.OutFileSize, 
       CheckFile.InFileSize - UnZipFile.OutFileSize as 'FileSizeDifference'
FROM [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] CheckFile
JOIN [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] UnZipFile ON CheckFile.InFileName = UnzipFile.OutFileName
WHERE CheckFile.JobGUID = 'Some GUID #' 
  and CheckFile.FunctionName = 'CheckFile'
  and UnZipFile.FunctionName = 'UnZipFile'
  and CheckFile.InFileName like '%.txt'
```

Comment: any dupes on column InFileName or OutFileName in your table [MY_TABLE]?

Comment: Try `select distinct`.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select distinct etc.
```

It should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT CheckFile.InFileName, CheckFile.InFileSize,
       UnZipFile.OutFileName, UnZipFile.OutFileSize,
       CheckFile.InFileSize - UnZipFile.OutFileSize as 'FileSizeDifference'
FROM [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] CheckFile
**INNER JOIN** [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] UnZipFile ON CheckFile.InFileName = UnzipFile.OutFileName
WHERE CheckFile.JobGUID = 'Some GUID #'
  and CheckFile.FunctionName = 'CheckFile'
  and UnZipFile.FunctionName = 'UnZipFile'
  and CheckFile.InFileName like '%.txt'
```

As per : [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

> INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables
>
> LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table
>
> RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table
>
> FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

Comment: The word `join` on it's own,  which is in the question, is an implicit inner join.